# How to customize SwipeToReferesh layout top ProgressBar or Loader?

Tags: android, loader

I would like to know how can I customize `SwipeToRefresh` layout. In specific, I am trying to hide that loader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please set following code into SwipetoReferesh Layout java file

```
layout.setProgressViewEndTarget(false,0);
layout.setProgressBackgroundColorSchemeColor(R.color.tra);
layout.setProgressBackgroundColorSchemeResource(R.color.tra);
```

**In color.xml file set tra =#ffffff**

Comment: :- Thank you for your feedback, It has been working perfectly Thank you so much.

Comment: Here ,You can find everything how to customization swipe to refresh layout.: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout#setProgressViewEndTarget(boolean,%20int)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this link. it's really explain everything. it's really useful.

Answer (score 3):

Copy & Past SwipetoReferesh Layout java file

```
layout.setProgressViewEndTarget(false,0);
layout.setProgressBackgroundColorSchemeColor(R.color.transparent);
layout.setProgressBackgroundColorSchemeResource(R.color.trasparent);
```

Create Custom color.xml file or make color code into string.xml get that color from the appropriate color file.

Reference link:- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout

NOTE:- set color code in Hexcode format.

Comment: it's working fine & share reference link for an official document.